# SSL 256 bit encryption - on Azure website

Tags: .net, ssl, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

With reference to the recent custom SSL provision for Azure website on the reserved instance - how can I enforce 256-bit encryption? All I see is the 128 bit using RC4_128. I want to ensure users connect using 256 bit encryption using AES_256.

The link provided does not have any input on this - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl-web-site/

Comment: So you want to enforce AES 256 from the server side? Azure websites seems to support the algorithm (try disabling 128 bit algorithms in Firefox and it will negotiate AES-256 instead of RC4_128) but decide against it.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this one. On Azure roles I could define the order of the cipher suites via power shell cmdlets, but on websites I think I can't

Comment: The cipher suite order is defined at the operating system level, not the application. For control over the operating system configuration you will need to use an Azure Web Role rather than a Azure Website.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS will always negotiate the highest protocol version that is supported by both the client and server in an encrypted conversation.
SSL 2.0, 3.0, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are deprecated, so the way to go is use **TLS 1.2**.

Answer (score 0):

Azure uses the following cipher suites:

Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order, then SSL 2 suites where used)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)     128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)     256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)  128 
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)     112 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)  128

Only XP clients would currently negotiate RC4 - this will soon change too.